# write a regex to test a string that * can only allow in the end

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex to test if a string is valid,

**Examples:**

```
"string152"  --> valid: allow both 0-9a-z
"string123*" --> valid: * is in the end
"s*tring123" --> invalid: * is not in the end
"*" --> valid: * is in the end
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: Something like `^[^*]*\*?$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also use

```
^[a-z0-9]+\*?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-z0-9]+` Match 1+ times a char a-z or a digit 0-9 to prevent an empty match
- `\*?` Optionally match `*`
- `$` Assert end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BRlq0l/1)

Comment: Hi, I tried only "*" , it shoud be valid but didn't work , could you please help me with this ? Thanks

Comment: @vincent I you don't want to match an empty string `^(?:[a-z0-9]+\*?|\*)$` https://regex101.com/r/yzAQeE/1

Comment: you really help me a lot, empty string should be valid, thanks a lot

Comment: If an empty string is also valid, you can make the whole group optional `^(?:[a-z0-9]+\*?|\*)?$` https://regex101.com/r/C0SZho/1

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
^[^*]*\*?$
```

pattern, where

```
 ^     - anchor, beginning of the string
 [^*]* - zero or more non-asterics symbols (any symbols but *)
 \*?   - optional asterics (zero or one)
 $     - anchor, end of the string
```